# How to store data with large number (constant) of properties in SQL

Tags: c++, python, sql, sqlite

I am parsing the USDA's food database and storing it in SQLite for query purposes.  Each food has associated with it the quantities of the same 162 nutrients.  It appears that the list of nutrients (name and units) has not changed in quite a while, and since this is a hobby project I don't expect to follow any sudden changes anyway.  But each food does have a unique quantity associated with each nutrient.

So, how does one go about storing this kind of information sanely.  My priorities are multi-programming language friendly (Python and C++ having preference), sanity for me as coder, and ease of retrieving nutrient sets to sum or plot over time.

The two things that I had thought of so far were 162 columns (which I'm not particularly fond of, but it does make the queries simpler), or a food table that has a link to a nutrient_list table that then links to a static table with the nutrient name and units.  The second seems more flexible i ncase my expectations are wrong, but I wouldn't even know where to begin on writing the queries for sums and time series.

Thanks

Comment: The second approach is the sensible one.

Comment: "Beginning Python: from novice to professional" by Magnus Lie Hetland has a section showing how to create a database application with Python and sqlite. As luck would have it, [he uses the USDA nutrient database for the example](http://books.google.com/books?id=S0l1YFpRFVAC&pg=PA300&lpg=PA300&dq=Python+Nutrient+Database&source=bl&ots=VCVZz1qYnR&sig=cdAMEVjckwmzCtYt8LRQa6JCsHg&hl=en&ei=3L7gTsa5Hqru0gHS6OjSBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Python%20Nutrient%20Database&f=false).

Comment: Both (current) answers are correct imho, but I will add that you should put a unique index on the "FoodNutrients" table across the Food and Nutrient foreign key columns.  Not only will this index speed up your lookup queries, it will also prevent you inserting the same nutrient for the same type of food.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read up a bit on [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Most of the normalization stuff is quite intuitive, but really going through the definition of the steps and seeing an example helps understanding the concepts and will help you greatly if you want to design a database in the future.

As for this problem, I would suggest you use 3 tables: one for the foods (let's call it `foods`), one for the nutrients (`nutrients`), and one for the specific nutrients of each food (`foods_nutrients`).

The foods table should have a unique index for referencing and the food's name. If the food has other data associated to it (maybe a link to a picture or a description), this data should also go here. Each separate food will get a row in this table.

The nutrients table should also have a unique index for referencing and the nutrient's name. Each of your 162 nutrients will get a row in this table.

Then you have the crossover table containing the nutrient values for each food. This table has three columns: `food_id`, `nutrient_id` and `value`. Each food gets 162 rows inside this table, oe for each nutrient.

This way, you can add or delete nutrients and foods as you like and query everything independent of programming language (well, using SQL, but you'll have to use that anyway :) ).

Let's try an example. We have 2 foods in the `foods` table and 3 nutrients in the `nutrients` table:

```
+------------------+
| foods            |
+---------+--------+
| food_id | name   |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | Banana |
| 2       | Apple  |
+---------+--------+

+-------------------------+
| nutrients               |
+-------------+-----------+
| nutrient_id | name      |
+-------------+-----------+
| 1           | Potassium |
| 2           | Vitamin C |
| 3           | Sugar     |
+-------------+-----------+

+-------------------------------+
| foods_nutrients               |
+---------+-------------+-------+
| food_id | nutrient_id | value |
+---------+-------------+-------+
| 1       | 1           | 1000  |
| 1       | 2           | 12    |
| 1       | 3           | 1     |
| 2       | 1           | 3     |
| 2       | 2           | 7     |
| 2       | 3           | 98    |
+---------+-------------+-------+
```

Now, to get the potassium content of a banana, your'd query:

```
SELECT food_nutrients.value
  FROM food_nutrients, foods, nutrients
  WHERE foods_nutrients.food_id = foods.food_id
    AND foods_nutrients.nutrient_id = nutrients.nutrient_id
    AND foods.name = 'Banana'
    AND nutrients.name = 'Potassium';
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the second (more normalized) approach.

You could even get away with fewer tables than you mentioned:

- tblNutrients
  -- NutrientID
  -- NutrientName
  -- NutrientUOM (unit of measure)
  -- Otherstuff
- tblFood
  -- FoodId
  -- FoodName
  -- Otherstuff
- tblFoodNutrients
  -- FoodID (FK)
  -- NutrientID (FK)
  -- UOMCount

It will be a nightmare to maintain a 160+ field database.

If there is a time element involved too (can measurements change?) then you could add a date field to the nutrient and/or the foodnutrient table depending on what could change.

Comment: The time element is somewhat at right angles and I probably shouldn't have brought it up.  There will also be a "meal" database that has a date and a link to a list of the foods and a quantity.  So the time series will be the meal quantity times the food summed up.